# Cannot insert object to HSQLDB with ActiveJDBC

Tags: java, hsqldb, activejdbc

I'm trying to use ActiveJDBC with HSQLDB:

Users.sql

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    "ID" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE seq NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

User.java

```
@IdName("ID")
public class User extends Model {....}
```

Main.java

```
User u = new User();
u.setFirstName("first_name");
u.setLastName("last_name");
u.save();
```

And when I try to save new row I have the following exception:

```
org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: id, Query: INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?), params: first_name,last_name
```

I think that problem in lower case in insert query. How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Why exactly is the ID name in double quotes in the create script?

Comment: As I understood from documentation double quotes make field name case sensetive

Comment: This has nothing  to do with the framework. Try executing the same without ActiveJDBC and resolve the privilege issue: INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?). 

Additionally, HSQL is not in a list of supported databases: http://javalite.io/activejdbc#supported-databases, but most things should still work out of the box .

Comment: @ipolevoy I executed and request works correctly without ActiveJDBC

Comment: @Nastya, can you enable loggin and see exactly what SQL is generated: http://javalite.io/logging, and add entire stack trace

Comment: I think problem in following ActiveJDBC code :
ps = e.prepareStatement(query, new String[]{autoIncrementColumnName}) 
in class org.javalite.activejdbc.DB#execInsert 
autoIncrementColumnName = this.getMetaModelLocal().getIdName() 

in class org.javalite.activejdbc.Model#insert 

and equals "id" (in lower case). But if I set this variable as "ID" (in upper case) it works correctly. Maybe you know why this.getMetaModelLocal().getIdName() return id in lower case if I set @IdName("ID")

Comment: I think the answer is http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/1.4.11/org/javalite/activejdbc/Model.html#toMap--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling for this HSQL exception message, I threw this code together that actually works. It uses ActiveJDBC, works with plain query and also works with instrumented model:

```
Base.open("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver", "jdbc:hsqldb:file:./target/tmp/hsql-test", "sa", "");

String create = "CREATE TABLE people (\n" +
        "    ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL,\n" +
        "    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,\n" +
        "    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL\n" +
        ");";

Base.exec(create);
Base.exec("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?)", "John", "Doe");

System.out.println("===>" + Base.findAll("select * from people"));

Person p = new Person();
p.set("first_name", "Jane", "last_name", "Doe").saveIt();

System.out.println(Base.findAll("select * from people"));
System.out.println(Person.findAll());
Base.close();
```

As you can see, the code that creates a table is a bit different, especially around the ID column.

The model looks like this:

```
@IdName("ID")
public class Person extends Model {}
```

Basically, you had the following issues with your code:

1. Definition of ID column with double quotes
2. ID column needs to be defined as IDENTITY (do not hold my feet to the fire, I'm no HSQL expert,  but t works)
3. The model needs to overwrite the `@IdName("ID")`, since ActiveJDBC defaults to lower case `id`, unless you change that in the table (why not?)

Keep in mind, that some things may not work, since HSQL is not on a list of supported databases.

I hope this helps!

Comment: `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE seq ` is fine but you need to `CREATE SEQUENCE seq AS INTEGER` first.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE seq NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: What exactly do I have to do from this? Because I did't understand